# What's the steps taken by Eclipse after PUBLISH? is PUBLISH means deploy?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just don't know what's goes on when we publish a web app, is it means deploy? where I can find the official doc about this?

Comment: [This](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwpub.html) might help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwpub.html

Hope this helps.